# Windows update doesn't work via double NAT for some computers

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, nat, windows-11, windows-store

Here is an issue that tortured me for some loooong time and I still can't wrap my head around it:

I've had huge issues updating Windows 11 on a brand new laptop of mine. It drove me crazy and I even reinstalled the OS because of it multiple times.

**Symptoms:**

- The computer connects to the internet perfectly fine, browsers can navigate fine.
- Windows update fails silently (while it reports a success - way to go Microsoft!)
- The Windows Store cannot download/update apps (it gives an error code that sends you in a fruitless internet hunt)
- Edge cannot update itself (reporting something ironic and silly - "updates are coming to you" - yes, in a century or two...).
- Downloading the trusted root certificates from [here](http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab) fails from the browser, but works with Opera's VPN enabled.

Multiple things came to my mind (expired root trust certificates, DNS issues, etc, etc). Nothing helped.

Then, I've noticed that I had similar issues on an ancient laptop with Windows 10, on the same local network. But another laptop I had, worked just fine on the same local network.

After some torture, installing trusted root certificates, changing DNS settings, and what not, I figured out that everything worked perfectly fine if I avoided my double NAT setup in my network.

I usually use CloudFlare's (`1.1.1.1`, `1.0.0.1`, etc) for DNS servers, but I have tried changing that too. Also, on Win11, I have tried with DNS encryption, without, etc, etc. Nothing helped. Also tried all kinds of troubleshooters and nothing helped.

**So, my questions are:**

- Any idea why everything works perfectly with double-NAT for one of my Win10 laptops, but horribly for my other two laptops (Win10+Win11)?
- Any idea how can this occur? I am suspecting that it might be related to DNS, since downloading from one of the problematic domains seems to work with Opera's VPN. But why the other laptop works without any problems? They all share the same DNS settings and the same routers!

I will try again with double-NAT after I update Windows and my drivers, just in case it starts working for all the machines, but I don't have high hopes because the Win11 laptop was pretty much up-to-date...

Comment: Internet via double NAT should not stop Windows Updates (I have done that before). Make sure you do not have an automatic VPN installed. Double NAT can stop these.

Comment: The Win11 machine was brand new. And I even reinstalled the OS from scratch, while trying to solve the problem. So, there was nothing installed on it. And I find it hard to believe the problem myself, because I was using double-NAT for quite some time on Win10 with zero problems.

Comment: Make sure if wireless you are not using a Public Connection.  Otherwise I am not sure. I have (numerous times) run Updates through a vanilla double NAT.

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps my inner router was forwarding DNS queries to some bad DNS server, but on its settings I had specifically selected Cloudflare's DNS servers. Plus, while using Secure DNS from Win11, I don't think that the router could intercept and alter those DNS queries...

Comment: Try connecting via your main router (that is, truly plain and vanilla connection).

Comment: @John I do not use wireless. All machines are on ethernet cables and all wireless functionality is disabled, both on the routers and on the machines. Also, all machines are on static IPs and DHCP is disabled.

Comment: Why double NAT? Also, why static IPs with disabled DHCP & why not use your ISP's DNS? All of these things are designed to make life easier; bypassing them means manually juggling things that just don't need it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am quite familiar with manual settings (plus, I don't like automatic things much) and I often need to call one PC from another, without using computer names. Also, I use double-NAT because I have something potentially-risky between my two routers that I want to protect my devices from.

Comment: Sound like you have a Rube Goldberg setup & are struggling accordingly. You do know you can have fixed IP addresses without switching off DHCP? Do you know how to compensate for lack of UPnP across double NAT? The way to have 'something risky' is to set it in a DMZ, separate from the rest of the network, not by using double NAT.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I know, but why have something enabled if I am not planning to use it? I don't like getting dynamic IPs and I don't like wondering what local IP I have. Also, I don't use UPnP and most likely I have that disabled as well on both routers. Yes, the built-in DMZ function of most routers might have helped, and it was on my list of considered options. But I went with trying to create a DMZ between the two routers myself instead. I am thinking of getting a switch with VLAN support lately. MikroTik seems to create somewhat cheap and effective VLAN switches.

Comment: Best comment thread ever! :-)

Comment: I wouldn't complicate a setup you've already admitted [probably without realising it] you don't understand in its current form. @BlindSpots - I'm trying to educate… it's not going too well so far ;)) Feel free to chime in.

Comment: @Tetsujin What makes you say I don't understand it? Working with static IPs is something a lot of people do and disabling UPnP is a common security practice. Also, the DMZ feature of most routers is not a real DMZ and I wouldn't trust it, especially since people from my ISP have administrative access to the router. From what I know, DMZs are normally created between two routers and not virtually, in some cheap router firmware. So, I definitely don't see what you are trying to educate me for and I don't see any ideas for what might be wrong. How are your comments related to my problem?

Comment: @Tetsujin Also, I know it works with a setup similar to what you describe. That's how I have it now and that's how it used to be some years ago. But my question is why it doesn't work with double-NAT, the way I want it. And why it used to work with double-NAT for some years until it started having problems recently.